# PHP checking Serial Number (data) exists before submiting data

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I am trying to run a php upload which checks to see if a serial number already exists then if it doesnt submits data.

so :

Submit form --> PHP Checks DB for Duplicate Serial number --> If Serial number Does not Exist then post data  // If Does Exist ignore input

However what ever i try doesnt seem to work. The following is my code but no matter what i do it submits the data even though the serial number already exists.

Form:

```
    <form id="form1" action="senddata.php" name="form1" method="post">
    <table class="table2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td colspan="3"><input type="button" onClick="update()" value="Get     Details"></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="description">Description:</label></td>
  <td><input tabindex="0" required type="text" name="description" id="description"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label for="nameofcomputer">Computer Code:</label></td>
  <td><input tabindex="1" required type="text" name="nameofcomputer" id="nameofcomputer"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label for="make">Make:</label></td>
  <td><input tabindex="2" required type="text" name="make" id="make"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label for="model">Model:</label></td>
  <td><input tabindex="3" required type="text" name="model" id="model"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label for="serial">Serial Number:</label></td>
  <td><input tabindex="4" required type="text" name="serial" id="serial"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="inputname">Your Name:  </label></td>
<td><input tabindex="5" required id="inputname" name="inputname">
</td>
</tr>

  </table>
<input required type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP

```
 $desc=$_POST['description'];
    $code=strtoupper($_POST['nameofcomputer']);
    $make=$_POST['make'];
    $model=$_POST['model'];
    $serial=strtoupper($_POST['serial']); 
    $user=$_POST['inputname'];


    $type='1';
    $org='-1';
    $control = "8670";
    $now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
    $date = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');




$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);    

$dupe = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Asset WHERE Serial_Number = '$serial'");
$num_rows = sqlsrv_num_rows($dupe);
if ($num_rows == 0) {
    $tsql = "INSERT INTO Asset (Name, Asset_Type_ID, Ref_Code, Owner_Organisation_ID, Make, Model, Serial_Number, Current_Location, Start_Date) 
    VALUES ('$desc', '$type', '$code', '$org', '$make', '$model', '$serial', '$user', '$date')";   
    sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
    echo "Asset Uploaded";
} else {
    echo 'Error! Already on our database!';
}
```

Any help to get this working is appreciated.

Comment: is your Serial_Number column is of integer type in db ?

Comment: I'd also try removing the brackets for this `WHERE (Serial_Number = '$serial')` plus, they're not needed.

Comment: Have you tried empty($dupe);  instead of $num_rows == 0 ?

Comment: ? please mention the datatype of Serial_Number column ?

Comment: also seeing another of your questions, you were using the MySQL_ API and now you're using `sqlsrv_`. You didn't introduce any `mysql_` anywhere did you? Again; the question's unclear. var_dump what the `$serial` variable gives you as well as dumping the entire query. You may even have whitespace being introduced. `var_dump($serial);` what does that say?

Comment: `$seriels = ($_POST['serial']);` what's with the typo? and make sure that row's value is uppercase, you're doing `strtoupper($_POST['serial'])`.

Comment: this is for a different project where there is no mysql at all. The field for serial is just a text field - same on the database i.e. ABC123DEF

Comment: `SELECT * FROM` - Use the serials column instead, not selecting "all". Your code's probably failing for many reasons. again, what's the var_dump for it? you also have some JS going on here `onClick="update()"`. which we don't know if that is relevant to the problem.

Comment: the update just auto updates the fields and is optional. it plays no part in the query functions

Comment: var_dump($serial) gives me string(8) "serialnumbervalue"

Comment: `ABC123DEF` that's 9 and your var_dump throws 8; something is getting trimmed somewhere. Make sure your column's length is long enough, otherwise your query will fail silently which seems to be the case here.

Comment: i was using abc123def as an example the column length is long enough. the example i used in my var_dump was 8 characters long.

Comment: If `WHERE Serial_Number = 'ABC123DEF'` works, then something is deleting your last character. Your `serialnumbervalue` doesn't tell me what the TRUE value is. If that isn't being changed to an uppercase, then there's the problem. There really isn't anything else I can do for you here, sorry. If `WHERE Serial_Number = 'abc123def'` works, then your value isn't being changed to uppercase. If you have more than one row with the same value, then that could be an issue. Try adding another clause to `WHERE`.

Comment: i have tried your suggestion of WHERE Serial_Number ='abc123def' and it doesnt work. the Changing to uppercase works as inserting data into the database has worked correctly until i put an if serial exists in there.And yest the abc123def exists in the database

Comment: I have tried another WHERE and still no luck

Comment: var_dump($num_rows) gives me bool(false)

Answer (score 0):

I replaced

```
$dupe = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT Serial_Number FROM Asset WHERE  Serial_Number = '$serial'");
```

with

```
$dupe = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT Serial_Number FROM Asset WHERE  Serial_Number = '$serial'", array(), array("Scrollable"=>"buffered"));
```

and it worked perfectly.

Thanks to those who helped me figure out where the code was going wrong.